# Magento Fatal error: include(): Cannot redeclare class varien_profiler in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I just copied over our files and database. Everything seems to be there with the right permissions and linked up to the right database and the right database pointing to the right path. Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: Related report: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333156/367456 - Which Magento version are you using? And which page is this?

Comment: Magento Version 1.12.0.2

Comment: The X-Ref doesn't have an answer either

Comment: From top of my head, Magento should log a backtrace to this error. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: There's no stacktrace on the page and nothing is logged to system.log or nginx/error.log

Comment: Okay, I see. Then uncomment line 92 in that file (`/lib/Varien/Autoload.php`) and report back the output when you reload the page. Also please tell the path of the URL you reload (host does not matter).

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting error.

> Magento Fatal error: include(): Cannot redeclare class varien_profiler in /lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

It's interesting because I'd expect to see `Varien_Profiler`, and not `varien_profiler'.  The line that's throwing this error is the last of your autoload method.

```
#File: lib/Varien/Autoload.php
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    //echo $classFile;die();
    return include $classFile;
}
```

What's odd about your error is it seems like someone tried to declare/use a

```
varien_profiler
```

class.  However, all the standard Magento references to this class are

```
Varien_Profiler
```

With leading word case.   When you use `Varien_Profiler`, Magento will try to include the file

```
lib/Varien/Profiler.php
```

However, in your case, Magento should try to include the file

```
lib/varien/profiler.php
```

Which is different — and doesn't exist in a standard installation.  I'm guessing you downloaded this from a heavily modified unix system — and pulled it down to a Mac or Windows system where case sensitivity isn't an issue.

All that's a long way of saying — this is an issue with your specific installation, and you'll need to debug it.  The best way, as other commenters have noted, is to get a stack trace and find out where the rouge `varien_profiler` is coming from, and then fix it so it's `Varien_Profiler`.  Temporarily modify the function above with the following code

```
if($class == 'varien_profiler')
{
    mageDebugBacktrace();
    exit;
}
return include $classFile;
```

This will output a simplified stack trace of files.php:line-number — something like this

```
[1] :
[2] /Users/alanstorm/Sites2014/magento-march2014.dev/app/Mage.php:665
[3] /Users/alanstorm/Sites2014/magento-march2014.dev/index.php:87
```

This should let you track down the rouge declaration.